# SSIS Multiple Loops propagate not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

My SSIS package attempts to loop through a list of people (in a table) then sends those people a list of reports.

If one of those reports are not generated (excel files) I would like the package not to fail but to continue.

I have read several articles on setting the propagate value to "false" which should mean the error does not bubble up to the containing loop.

It still does :(

I have set the maximum error to 0 on the "Send Email Task" and added an Error event with the propagate value set to "false"

The event fails but also fails the above loop and therefore the package.

I even added a sequence container to see if that would help! No joy :(

The only way I can get it to work is by setting the Maximum error count on all loops to 0 which seems wrong.

[image: SSIS]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "max error count" of a container ignores any propagation settings set on child items. It lets you define the number of errors that are allowed to occur in any child item before the container itself fails. The idea here is that you may have a situation where you want the parent to fail only if more than say, 10 child items fail, irrespective of where they fail.

If you want to prevent this from occuring, you need to change the count to 0, which turns off this check, and allows your child items to fail as many times as you like.

In your case, you want the loop to always continue no matter how many child items fail.

1. Set the mail task to *not* fail the parent when the task fails.
2. Change the settings on the container objects to have the max error count to zero, and "fail parent when this task fails" to true.

Once these are set, the mail task will fail but the loop will continue. If another item in your flow fails, error propagation will fail the parent group up the chain.

Comment: Argh, I have read your answer a few times and not sure I can make sense of it. Are you saying that setting the error count to zero is correct thing to do in this instance? What is the point of the propagate flag then? :)

Comment: I have clairified my answer somewhat, does this help?