# DTexec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, dtexec

I have a package in SSIS and is getting an error when I try to run it by .bat file (when I run from a SSIS solution this errors never comes).

The error:

> Description: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED. The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of error reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
>   End Waning
>   DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).

Reading all the log information, I get an overflow error in a destination column. Thats ok, I know about that error, but the thing is I need the process succeed anyway.

This is because I generate a message when the container fail, to inform about that, but I need the process continue and finish "OK" although there is an error.

Comment: You need to set the maximum error count of the package or the container. See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972340/ssis-multiple-loops-propagate-not-working/8972791#8972791

Comment: I change the property MaximumErrorCount to 0 or 10 and always get the same error.

Comment: Why does the execution fail? Address the root cause.There are failure messages before the generic one posted. Those are what is needed to begin to diagnose the error

Comment: There is an overflow error. But I don't have to fix it, the dtsx must continue and log an execution line in the log table. So it has to finish as success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting FailPackageOnFailure and FailParentOnFailure properties of DFT to FALSE with MaximumErrorCount set to 0.
Alternatively, you could use OnError handler and set the System variable "Propogate" to FALSE.

Comment: I try it. By default they have FailPackageOnFailure and FailParentOnFailure on FALSE. I try changing MaximumErrorCount to 0 and Propagate to FALSE, but the DTSER_FAILURE (1) continue showing.